# Surface Normals OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es

So, I am working on an OpenGL ES 2.0 terrain rendering program still.
I have weird drawing happening at the tops of ridges. I am guessing this is due to surface normals not being applied.

So, I have calculated normals.
I know that in other versions of OpenGL you can just activate the normal array and it will be used for culling.
To use normals in OpenGL ES can I just activate the normals or do I have to use a lighting algorithm within the shader?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to supply any screenshots?

Comment: On SO, computer graphics is more a niche. However, a picture may tell more than a thousand words to seasoned devs.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL doesn't use normals for culling. It culls based on whether the projected triangle has its vertices arranged clockwise or anticlockwise. The specific decision is based on (i) which way around you said was considered to be front-facing via `glFrontFace`; (ii) which of front-facing and/or back-facing triangles you asked to be culled via `glCullFace`; and (iii) whether culling is enabled at all via `glEnable`/`glDisable`.

Culling is identical in both ES 1.x and 2.x. It's a fixed hardware feature. It's external to the programmable pipeline (and, indeed, would be hard to reproduce within the ES 2.x programmable pipeline because there's no shader with per-triangle oversight).

If you don't have culling enabled then you are more likely to see depth-buffer fighting at ridges as the face with its back to the camera and the face with its front to the camera have very similar depths close to the ridge and limited precision can make them impossible to distinguish correctly.

Lighting in ES 1.x is calculated from the normals. Per-vertex lighting can produce weird problems at hard ridges because normals at vertices are usually the average of those at the faces that join at that vertex, so e.g. a fixed mesh shaped like `\/\/\/\/\` ends up with exactly the same normal at every vertex. But if you're not using 1.x then that won't be what's happening.

To implement lighting in ES 2.x you need to do so within your shader. As a result of that, and of normals not being used for any other purpose, there is no formal way to specify normals as anything special. They're just another vertex attribute and you can do with them as you wish.

Comment: I am using ES 2.0. I do have culling enabled and my winding order is fine. Interesting that in 1.0 lighting is calculated from normals. I've hear a little bit about Z fighting which maybe could be an issue.

Comment: ... in which case the follow-up questions would be whether your projection matrix uses the available depth range to the maximum extent possible and, if you're doing terrain, whether it's arranged in a sufficiently regular pattern (e.g. it's a height map) that you could render it correctly without a depth buffer. If so then probably the smartest thing would probably be to prime the depth buffer with correct values, then render back-to-front with a slight offset. So front still overdraws where there's ambiguity but the priming hopefully discards the majority of expensive fragment calculations.

Comment: (with depth writing disabled on the real draw pass, so you can then render non-terrain objects as per usual)

Comment: My terrain is arranged ina  sufficuently regular patters as they are z values in metres from a height map file. What do you mean by "prime the depth buffer with correct values, then render back-to-front with a slight offset"? On a side: does a more precise calculation of the near and far clip planes when building a projection matrix add more precision to the depth buffer?

Comment: If you render front to back without a depth buffer you'll get the correct view but you'll spend a lot on fragment shading for a lot of fragments that are never seen. If you first draw with a completely trivial shader (and `glColorMask` set to disable things) then you'll put the right values into the depth buffer. If you then draw back-to-front with the depth test enabled, your normal shader and a slight `glPolygonOffset` then you'll get correct draw order with most invisible fragments being discarded without processing.

Comment: You should always be as correct as you can be in the projection matrix as the depth buffer is set up to store values between 0 and 1; if you end up using only a subrange of those values then you'll use only a subrange of the available precision. So you'll get less precision than you could.

Comment: Okay. I'll do some testing. Thanks for the help. I definitely wasn't being very accurate with the depth buffer.